# ExpressibleByBooleanLiteralの実装について

Tags: swift

ExpressibleByBooleanLiteralプロトコルを適合した型で、
if文でその変数の状態だけで、判断してほしいのですができません。
if g {}が可能になるにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

enum Grade : ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral{
    case A,B,C,D,E

```
var boolValue : Bool{
    switch self{
        case .A,.B,.C:
            return true
        default:
            return false
    }
}
init(booleanLiteral value: Bool){
    if value{
        self = .A    
    }else{
        self = .E
    }

}
```

}

var g = Grade.A

if g {//コンパイルが通らない！！
    print("合格")
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

結論から言うと`ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral`は異なる目的のためのプロトコルで、あなたが所望の動作を行うためのプロトコルはSwift 3で廃止されました。

---

`ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral`と言うのはSwiftのboolean literal(`true`または`false`のみ)を自身のデータ型として扱えるようにするためのプロトコルです。

`ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral`に適合させた型に対してはこんな書き方ができるようになります:

```
//`Grade`型の変数に`true`や`false`を代入したり
let g: Grade = true //(この例は本当は代入ではなく、宣言の初期化だが本当の代入もできる)
func someFunc(grade: Grade) {
    print(grade)
}
//`Grade`型のパラメータに`true`や`false`を渡したり
someFunc(grade: false) //->E
```

---

あなたがご所望の機能(`if`の条件部など`Bool`型が必要な場所で明示的な型変換を書かなくても、`Bool`型の値に変換してくれる)は、古いSwiftで`BooleanType`とか`Boolean`とか呼ばれていたもの(Swiftのバージョンによりコロコロと名前が変わっています)ですが、Swift 3で正式に廃止されました。

[Xcode Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051)中の**Xcode 8.0**内の[Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW146)の項目内を探すと("Boolean"あたりで検索してみてください)、次の素っ気ない1行が見つかります。

> - The Boolean protocol has been removed. ([SE-0109](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0109-remove-boolean.md))

SE-0109と言うのはswift.org内のSwift Evolution(Swiftの進化)での公式提案の一つですが、**Introduction**のところを要約すると:

> `Bool`と`Boolean`なんて初心者にはややこしいだけだし、元々Objective-Cの`BOOL`をうまくSwift側にブリッジするために考えたんだけど今は`BOOL`はほとんど完璧に`Bool`にブリッジされちゃうし、そもそも標準ライブラリの中でも一貫した使われ方してないし(…だからもうそんなもの要らないよね。)

---

と言うわけで今更何かの役に立つというわけではないですが(Appleは「Swift2をサポートするのはXcode8.2が最後だから、さっさとSwift3に移行しろ」としつこくアナウンスしています)、Swift 2の時代にはこんな書き方ができたというのを紹介しておきます。(Xcode 8.2でもLegacy Swiftの設定をYESにしたプロジェクトを作れば試せます。)

```
enum Grade : BooleanType {
    case A,B,C,D,E

    var boolValue : Bool {
        switch self {
        case .A,.B,.C:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}

var g = Grade.A

if g {
    print("合格") //->合格
}
```

---

Swift 3の場合、あきらめて

```
if g.boolValue {
    print("合格") //->合格
}
```

と書くか、逆にもっと中身を表すわかりやすい名前をつけて、そちらの方を使うと言うのが(Swift開発チームの考える)正しい使い方と言うことになるのでしょう。

```
enum Grade {
    case A,B,C,D,E

    //合格ならtrue
    var passes : Bool {
        switch self {
        case .A,.B,.C:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}

var g = Grade.A

if g.passes {
    print("合格") //->合格
}
```